# Is there an equivalent of "adiabatic" for work (i.e. a workless transformation)?

Tags: thermodynamics, work, reversibility, adiabatic

In **Fermi's Thermodynamics (1937)**, Chapter I, §1, he defines an *isochore transformation* as

> a transformation during which the system performs no external work

He then discusses the case where the infinitesimal work $dL$ performed by the system on the surroundings has the form $dL = pdV$ and that in this case $dL = 0$ implies $dV = 0$ and so the transformation must be at contante volume $V$.

However, he then stresses that

> the concept of *isochore transformation* is more general, since it requires that $dL = 0$ for the given transformation, even when the work $dL$ cannot be represented by [the equation $dL = p dV$].

Today, *isochore* means "at constant volume".

However, this makes me wonder: is there nowadays a term to mean "without performing work"—similarly as *adiabatic* means "without exchange of heat"?

Answer (score 3):

Work comes in a variety of flavors (pressure–volume, force–length, stress–volumetric strain, surface tension–surface area, electric field–polarization, voltage–charge, magnetic field–magnetization, etc.), so although one could say that all relevant [generalized displacements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_variables_(thermodynamics)) are *fixed*, it's less ambiguous to just say that the system does no work.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is any widely-agreed general term for heat transfer without work, and this implies that there does not need to be.

It should be mentioned in this context that the term 'adiabatic' is, in practice, often misused or used differently from how it was defined.

Whenever people say they mean by it 'without heat transfer' they then proceed to use it in the sense 'reversible and at constant system entropy.' For example, one speaks of lines of constant $S$ on an indicator diagram as 'adiabats', and one speaks of 'adiabatic compressibility' etc. This is so widespread that I think it is now better to define 'adiabatic' as 'reversible and without heat transfer'.

If 'adiabatic' really just means 'no heat transfer' then irreversible processes such as explosions inside an isolated system would be called 'adiabatic', which contradicts the way the word is used in quantum mechanics and the rest of physics. So I have encouraged us to adopt the usage implied in the rest of physics.

Comment: Pippard, in *Elements of Classical Thermodynamics* (1964, pp 16, 31) defines *adiabatic* as you suggest, but *adiathermal* as without heat entering or leaving the system, whether or not the process is reversible. Rather helpful, I think.

Answer (score 1):

"Heat conduction" is surely "workless" but nonconservative entropy transport, but I do not know of any *other* that would be completely workless.

Answer (score 0):

The thermodynamics concept of work (and heat) becomes too mired in arguments, and so it is better to just be precise in stating what process, what are constant, it is that you are meaning, and be done with it.

Comment: Maybe this should have been a comment, but I actually agree with your assessment. Thermodynamics questions have a tendency to be "as general as possible", which is counterproductive to drilling down on an actual problem.